# How to fix mgp.Vertex.properties not JSON serializable?

Tags: memgraphdb

I am creating a query module in Memgraph and I am creating a dictionary for every node in the database. I am trying to add properties of a node as a list to my properties key, but then I get `mgp.Vertex.properties` not `JSON` serializable error. What is the best way to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because `mgp` objects are not `JSON` serializable, and there is a [feature request](https://github.com/memgraph/memgraph/issues/313) opened for that. But, to avoid such error for now, you can do similar to what is implemented in the [export_util.py](https://github.com/memgraph/mage/blob/main/python/export_util.py#L91-L94) query module. You iterate over all properties for every node and depending on the property type, set value for every key.